# first person shooter movement always adds offset

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a doom style game in pygame and currently work on the player movement and want to create the movement style where pressing forward means the player goes towards the viewing direction instead of going up and down on the coordinate system.

The code I have is this:

```
import pygame, sys, math

class Player:
    def __init__(self,pos,speed,surface):
        self.pos = pos
        self.surface = surface
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0,0)
        self.speed = speed
        self.angle = 0

    def get_input(self):
        sin_a = math.sin(self.angle)
        cos_a = math.cos(self.angle)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.direction.y = sin_a
            self.direction.x = cos_a
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.direction.y = -sin_a
            self.direction.x = -cos_a
        else:
            self.direction.y = 0
            self.direction.x = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.angle += 0.02
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.angle -= 0.02

    def move(self):
        self.pos += self.direction * self.speed

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.surface,'Red',self.pos,10)
        x = self.pos[0] + 1280 * math.cos(self.angle)
        y = self.pos[1] + 720 * math.sin(self.angle)
        pygame.draw.line(self.surface,'Red',self.pos,(x,y))

    def run(self):
        self.get_input()
        self.move()
        self.draw()

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Player([640,360],4,screen)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    
    screen.fill('black')
    player.run()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

So I am using sin and cos to calculate the viewing direction and the forward/backward movement. However, an offset is always added when moving. So when the player moves forward there is an additional upward movement and backwards movement shifts the player down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the point (red circle) was actually moving in the right direction. The issue was the red line that indicated the direction. You've scaled each component of your direction vector by a different value and hence you were producing points that were not on the same line.

The fix is to use a fixed scale factor (for example `1000`) for both components.

Replace:

```
x = self.pos[0] + 1280 * math.cos(self.angle)
y = self.pos[1] + 720 * math.sin(self.angle)
```

with:

```
x = self.pos[0] + 1000 * math.cos(self.angle)
y = self.pos[1] + 1000 * math.sin(self.angle)
```

Comment: oh god, that is such a silly and obvious error!  Thank you so much, works like a charm now